# How to retain '\s' in Google App Script regex

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently populating a boilerplate formula in a Google Sheet after moving the rest of the data to another sheet, however the formula seems to drop the '' from '\s' in the sheet,leading to the regex detecting and replacing all S's rather than whitespace.

e.g. `REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\s","")` becomes `REGEXREPLACE(A2,"s","")`

The full code is:

```
descriptionSheet.appendRow(['Brand', 
                            'Product Type', 
                            'Product Name', 
                            'Size', 
                            'Colour', 
                            'Condition', 
                            '', 
                            '=VLOOKUP(D2&" "&A2&" "&B2,Measurements!A:C,2,FALSE)', '=VLOOKUP(D2&" "&A2&" "&B2,Measurements!A:C,3,FALSE)', '=A2&" "&IF(C2="","",C2&" ")&B2&"\n\n"&D2&"\n"&E2&"\n\n"&F2&" condition - "&IF(G2="","No rips, holes or stains!",G2)&"\n\nMeasurements\n⦿ Pit to pit: "&H2&" inch\n⦿ Shoulder hem to bottom: "&I2&" inch\n\nVerified Depop Top Seller! Shop with confidence.\n\nFree Shipping on bundles.\nSame day dispatch on request.\n\n#"&REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\s","")&" #"&REGEXREPLACE(A2&B2,"-|\s","")&" #"&REGEXREPLACE(K2,"-|\s","")', '=CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2," ",C2)', '=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"[^A-ZÀ-Ö]","")&"-"&REGEXREPLACE(K2,"[^A-Z0-9]","")&"-"&D2&"-"&SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(JOIN("",ArrayFormula(left(split(F2," "),1)))),"-","")&"-"&UPPER(LEFT(E2,3))'
                        ]);
```

Note the \n is working as desired. Only the \s is causing an issue.

Tried using String.raw and changing code to use /\s/g instead of just \s

Comment: To be clear in your first example it is NOT what is in the code `REGEXREPLACE(A2&B2,"-|\s","")&" #"&REGEXREPLACE(K2,"-|\s","")`

Comment: Thanks Mark. It is in my code. We produce 3 hashtags:  #"&REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\s","")&" #"&REGEXREPLACE(A2&B2,"-|\s","")&" #"&REGEXREPLACE(K2,"-|\s",""). I've used only the first one in my message above for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**

As I see In your Google Sheets formula, the backslash and 's' characters are not preserved properly, resulting in the incorrect interpretation of the regex pattern. So, the '\s' is not recognized as intended, and all occurrences of 's' are being replaced instead of whitespace.

**Solution** (I'm not 100% sure)

To resolve this issue, you need to escape the backslash by using double backslashes ('') to ensure the preservation of the characters.

**Code:**

```js
descriptionSheet.appendRow([
  'Brand',
  'Product Type',
  'Product Name',
  'Size',
  'Colour',
  'Condition',
  '',
  '=VLOOKUP(D2&" "&A2&" "&B2,Measurements!A:C,2,FALSE)',
  '=VLOOKUP(D2&" "&A2&" "&B2,Measurements!A:C,3,FALSE)',
  '=A2&" "&IF(C2="","",C2&" ")&B2&"\n\n"&D2&"\n"&E2&"\n\n"&F2&" condition - "&IF(G2="","No rips, holes or stains!",G2)&"\n\nMeasurements\n⦿ Pit to pit: "&H2&" inch\n⦿ Shoulder hem to bottom: "&I2&" inch\n\nVerified Depop Top Seller! Shop with confidence.\n\nFree Shipping on bundles.\nSame day dispatch on request.\n\n#"&REGEXREPLACE(A2,String.raw`\\s`,"")&" #"&REGEXREPLACE(A2&B2,"-|\\s","")&" #"&REGEXREPLACE(K2,"-|\\s","")',
  '=CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2," ",C2)',
  '=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"[^A-ZÀ-Ö]","")&"-"&REGEXREPLACE(K2,"[^A-Z0-9]","")&"-"&D2&"-"&SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(JOIN("",ArrayFormula(left(split(F2," "),1)))),"-","")&"-"&UPPER(LEFT(E2,3))'
]);
```